# Setando largura e altura de uma ImageView

Tags: android

Olá, preciso alterar o tamanho de uma `ImageView` através da **class.java** e não sei bem o comando.

Segue meu código

***xml***

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewVermelho"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

***class.java***

```
iv_vermelho = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewVermelho);
```

preciso setar o tamanho da imagem aqui

ex:
se fosse fazer no xml seria assim

```
android:layout_width="104dp"
android:layout_height="104dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Para alterar parametros da uma `View` (qualquer uma que a herde), você pode utilizar a classe nativa `LayoutParams`.

No seu caso, para alterar o tamanho de sua `ImageView` dinamicamente, tente algo parecido:

```
ImageView iv_vermelho = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewVermelho);

//Acessando o LayoutParams de sua View
iv_vermelho.getLayoutParams().width = algumValor;
iv_vermelho.getLayoutParams().height = outroValor;
```

Comment: Amigo esse algumValor; e outroValor; qual é a medida eu preciso de coloca em dp pois quando eu coloco  iv_vermelho.getLayoutParams().width = algumValor; fica tudo desconfigurado dependendo da resolução do aparelho

Comment: @KleberSouza esse valor é dado em pixel. Você pode obter o valor equivalente em dp com:   `pixelsValue  / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`